# Не войти в SourceeTree. Кто знает, что не так делаю?

Tags: контроль-версий, source-tree

Сегодня после обновления SourceeTree от Atlassian программа снова требует, посещения личного аккаунта.
Ну посетил я аккаунт, ну снова скачал лицензионный ключ, снова скопировал его в папку с программой (прошлый раз так активировал) ... а сейчас - глухо ... ни программу не открыть, ни указать лицензионный ключ ... ничего не сделать ...[image]

Закрытие программы или перезагрузка ничем не помогает ... посети аккаунт и всё тут ...посетил уже раз 10 - бестолку ... :( Кто знает, что не так делаю?

Comment: попробуйте обратиться в саппорт Atlassian

Comment: бесполезно, в который раз нарываюсь у них на это: http://savepic.ru/8778499.jpg

Comment: @Алексей, подождите пока сайт поднимется (хотя бы сутки), потом попробуйте еще раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

До сих пор сайт тех поддержки Atlassian SourceTree - лежит "мёртвым".

Но программа заработала: пришлось войти используя существующий аккаунт ("use an existing account") через аккаунт Google+ и всё, инсталляция продолжилась.

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с 8-й версии, для оффлайн-активации, файл `sourcetree.license` нужно класть в:

- В Windows - `%localappdata%\Atlassian\SourceTree`(можете нажать <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, вставить этот путь туда, и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd> - попадёте в нужный каталог)
- В OSX - `~/Library/Application Support/SourceTree/`

А вовсе не в папку с исполняемым файлом.

Comment: Странно, а как же у меня это вышло в прошлый раз :)
Но суть не в этом, я сделал как вы сказали, скопировал файл в эту папку ... а окно ни куда не исчезает и ничего не сделать ... :(